# Рекурсивная функция вычисления корня уравнения

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Написать рекурсивную функцию вычисления корня уравнения `f(x) = 0` на заданном интервале `[a, b]` и `с` точностью `e`.

Функция `f` задается в исходном коде программы (проверяющим), числа `a`, `b` и `е` задаются в консоле. В качестве функции `f(x)` может быть, например, выражение `х + 5*(х-3)`.

Не пойму даже с чего начать, к чему ограничение интервалом? 
Я примерно понимаю, как вычислить корень из числа, но из функции даже примерного понятия не имею. Я не прошу писать код, просто буду рад любой наводке.

Comment: наводка: учить математику в объеме 8-го класса средней школы, чтобы знать, чем отличается корень из числа от корня уравнения.

Comment: господи, извините, чет голову пронесло..

Comment: Если у вас вас проблема исчезла, напишите об этом

Comment: Проблема исчезла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такое как метод хорд, касательных, половинного деления. Рекомендую посмотреть сначала последний, так как он на мой взгляд самый понятный.

Comment: да, благодарю.
я просто немного невнимательно прочел задание и меня понесло не туда.